# How to update an uploaded file in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

```
public function update($id)
    {
        $validation = MarketingMaterial::validator_edit(Input::all());

        if ($validation->fails()) {

            return Redirect::to('marketing_materials/'. $id . '/edit')->withErrors($validation);

        } else {


            $marketing_material                                  = MarketingMaterial::findOrFail($id);

            $old_title = $marketing_material->title;


            $marketing_material->title                           = Input::get('title');
            $marketing_material->description                     = Input::get('description');
            $marketing_material->marketing_materials_category_id = Input::get('marketing_materials_category_id');


            $thumb_path = Input::file('thumb_path');

            if (Input::hasFile('thumb_path'))
            {

                $file            = Input::file('thumb_path');
                $destinationPath = base_path().'/app/files/marketing_materials/'.$marketing_material->title.'/thumb_path/';
                $filename        = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $extention       = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filesize        = $file->getSize();
                $uploadSuccess   = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);


                $marketing_material->thumb_path = $filename;
            }


            $media_path = Input::file('media_path');

            if (Input::hasFile('media_path'))
            {

                $file            = Input::file('media_path');
                $destinationPath = base_path().'/app/files/marketing_materials/'.$marketing_material->title.'/media_path/';
                $filename        = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $extention       = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filesize        = $file->getSize();
                $uploadSuccess   = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);


                $marketing_material->media_path = $filename;
                $marketing_material->media_size = $filesize;
            }



            dd($old_title);

            $marketing_material->save();


            return Redirect::to('marketing_materials')
            ->with('success','The electronic marketing material was updated succesfully!');
        }
    }
```

**Goal:**

Able to edit an uploaded file (file that already uploaded).

Controller --> update function

As you can see, I rely my destination path, on my title, as soon as the user change the title, everything will be mess up.

I'm not sure how to go around that.

**Question:**

Can someone tell me how to get around this in Laravel 4 or point me to the right direction ?

Thanks.

**Screenshots**

[My Form](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/1.JPG)

[Error](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/2.JPG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function update($id)
{
    $validator = CatalogDownload::edit_validator(Input::all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('catalog_downloads/'. $id . '/edit')
        ->withErrors($validator);

    }else {


        $catalog_download        = CatalogDownload::findOrFail($id);
        $catalog_download->title = Input::get('title');
        $catalog_download->note  = Input::get('note');

        $catalog_download->save();





        foreach (ExportType::all() as $export_type)
        {




            if (Input::hasFile('type_' . $export_type->id))
            {



                $success = File::deleteDirectory(base_path().'/app/files/product_export/'. $catalog_download->id.'/'. $export_type->id.'/'); // Answer





                $product_export  = new ProductExport;

                $zip             = Input::file('type_' . $export_type->id);
                $filename        = $zip->getClientOriginalName();
                $filesize        = $zip->getSize();

                $destinationPath = base_path().'/app/files/product_export/'. $catalog_download->id.'/'. $export_type->id.'/';
                $uploadSuccess   = $zip->move($destinationPath, 'Bioss 2015 Catalog.zip' );




                if  (!isset($uploadSuccess )) 
                {
                    return Redirect::to('catalog_downloads/create')
                    ->with('error', 'Problem during upload')
                    ->withInput();          
                }


                $product_export->file_path           =  'Bioss 2015 Catalog.zip';

                $product_export ->exported_date      = DateHelper::getDateFormatMySQL(Input::get('exported_date'));
                $product_export->catalog_download_id = $catalog_download->id;
                $product_export->export_type_id      = $export_type->id;




                $product_export->size                = $filesize;




                $product_export->save();
            }


        }


        return Redirect::to('catalog_downloads/')
        ->with('success','The catalog_download was updated successfully!');

    }
}
```

The Code above is the solution for it.

The magic happened in this line :

```
$success = File::deleteDirectory(base_path().'/app/files/product_export/'. $catalog_download->id.'/'. $export_type->id.'/');
```

**Solution**

I deleted old files, and then re-create new files.